# Global ServerName directive returns Syntax Error

Tags: apache, ubuntu, config

I am trying to configure an Apache2 Server, I ran the command to check its status and got the error that my global serverName is not set, so I googled how to do it and it worked fine, I opened the apache2.conf file and put in the server name I got through running this:

`hostname` and then I put in the server IP, as seen here:

```
# Global configuration
#
lehner-tse01 132.231.36.101
```

However when I run `apachectl configtest` or when I try to restart apache I get this error:

```
Invalid command 'lehner-tse01', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I cant rename the server and I didn't find anything googling for the second part of the error message.

Comment: That's a configuration for /etc/hosts, not for Apache's conf files. Also, not programming related - e.g. off topic [help/on-topic].

Comment: @OlafKock really? Because when I googled the error message that was what came up first. Then I ll deleted it again, thank you for your answer!

Comment: It's not that everything that google spits out is true, and especially not in any and all cases and specific situations. Apache directives are `Directive Parameter` - and "Directive" would need to be known. Apache httpd does not know about a directive named "lehner-tse01", thus the error message

Comment: @OlafKock ah yeah the explanation makes sense. Its just like a foreign language to me since it is my first time working with it. But hey, at least it changed from a blank white page to a 403 error now haha